# Configuring SSL connection for Oracle 12

Tags: oracle, ssl, encryption, jdbc

I am trying to configure an Oracle 12 instance to allow (and later force) SSL-encrypted connections (only encryption, no authentication).

I did like described in [SSL With Oracle JDBC Thin Driver](http://www.oracle.com/%20technetwork/%20database/%20enterprise-edition/%20wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf):

Changed in `listener.ora` from

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

to

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 2484))
    )
  )

WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/tmp/oracle_wallet_tmp)))
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
```

and also added the last two lines to sqlnet.ora.

I then created the wallet with

```
orapki wallet create -wallet /tmp/oracle_wallet_tmp  -pwd test1234
```

and restarted the listener with

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

The non-encryption session still works fine.
But

But when trying to connect via JDBC on an encrypted connection I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Fehler: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:682)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
  at orassl.Orassl.<init>(Orassl.java:23)
  at orassl.Orassl.main(Orassl.java:38)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
  at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
  at oracle.net.ns.Packet.send(Packet.java:419)
  at oracle.net.ns.ConnectPacket.send(ConnectPacket.java:241)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:151)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
  ... 8 more
```

The listener log file `listener/alert/log.xml` only tells me

```xml
<msg time='2014-03-04T14:03:19.906+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='myhost'
 host_addr='hostip'>
 <txt>04-MAR-2014 14:03:19 * &lt;unknown connect data&gt; * 12561
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-03-04T14:03:19.907+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='myhost'
 host_addr='hostip'>
 <txt>TNS-12561: TNS:unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-03-04T14:03:19.933+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='myhost'
 host_addr='hostip'>
 <txt>04-MAR-2014 14:03:19 * &lt;unknown connect data&gt; * 12561
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-03-04T14:03:19.933+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='myhost'
 host_addr='hostip'>
 <txt>TNS-12561: TNS:unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
```

The client connects with the following:

```java
props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites", "(SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)");
props.setProperty("user", "dbuser");
props.setProperty("password", "dbpass");
final Connection c= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=hostip)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=mysid)))", props );
```

What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: This is a generic error. Enable tracing to get more details on this error.

Answer (score 1):

Two important points I found getting SSL working (JDBC with SQLDeveloper, sqlplus command)

- The withepaper's comment regarding the anonymous DH ciphers isn't valid for 12c anymore, you should be OK with the standard ciphers – in my case, commenting out the `SSL_CIPHER_SUITES` on servers `sqlnet.ora` and `listner.ora` did the trick.
- In the database you have to explictly set the `local_listener` parameter to a value that supports SSL. For simplicity you can copy your LISTENER config from `listener.ora` to `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` and then set your `local_listener` to that value, e.g. `alter system set local_listener='LISTENER';`
- The 256bit AES Ciphers don't work out of the box with Java – you have to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)

If you have access to Metalink,  Note 762286.1, "End To End Examples of using SSL With Oracle's JDBC THIN Driver (Doc ID 762286.1)" might help.

One more hint: as XML tends to be a bit hard to read, you can examine the plain text log file under the trace subdirectory. e.g. `/u01/app/diag/tnslsnr/$HOST/listener/trace/listener.log`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. I already had the SSL_CIPHER_SUITES commented out. Installing the JCE also doesn't solve the problem. Since I am doing the connection from a java application the `local_listener` doesn't apply here. So still no solution...

Comment: The local_listener still applys to you, as the listener redirects the connection to the database. You have to set it explicitly in the database per  default it listens to $HOSTIP:1521. So if you set up the listener with a nice and shiny new SSL Port the database does not know anything about it. In my case, I could see the connection in the listener.log, but then the connection wasn't reconnected to the dedicated database process, because the database wasn't aware of this connection. So setting local_listener did solve the problem at least for me.

Comment: So, I tried it now. Edited tnsnames.ora and added `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 2484))` to the listener defined ther. I then did an `alter system set local_listener='MY_LISTENER'. But it didn't change anything. Actually I do not really understand what this local_listener is used for.